# sec:authorize not being evaluated on spring-boot project

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dialect

In my current spring-boot project, I have one view with this html code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
     ...
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
     ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

but when I execute the application, apparently the tag `sec:authorize` isn't being evaluated, since both parts are being displayed.

I configure thymeleaf in my application.properties file this way:

```
# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

my thymeleaf configuration class is implemented this way:

```
@Configuration
public class Thymeleaf {
  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine  =  new SpringTemplateEngine();
    final Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
    dialects.add( new SpringSecurityDialect() );
    engine.setDialects( dialects );

    return engine;
  }
}
```

anyone can point what i am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add the following dependency for Thymeleaf:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also make sure to add this to the `<html>`

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
```

I also dont think that `Set<IDialect>` is necessary (correct me if I'm wrong), You can just write it as:

```
Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
   SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
   engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
   engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
   return engine;
}
```