# Updated dependencies and Thymeleaf tags don't work

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Updated my dependencies and project to Spring Boot 2.1.1 which is the latest version and suddenly security tags don't work. I'm using Thymeleaf.

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"> <!-- Doesn't work -->
      ...
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sec:authorize not being evaluated on spring-boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367386/secauthorize-not-being-evaluated-on-spring-boot-project)

Comment: Not really because Spring Boot 2.1 uses different dependencies

Comment: And you tried `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"` as in the linked answer?  (Or in this case springsecurity5)

Comment: Neither. I used `xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`. So, the only thing that needs changing is the dependency.

Comment: Ok, glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#thymeleaf-spring-security-extras

> Dependency management and auto-configuration for Thymeleaf’s Spring Security Extras module has switched from thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 to thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5. If you were using the module, you should update your pom.xml or build.gradle to depend upon thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5.

So the updated pom.xml should change the following dependency from:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
     <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`
```

to:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
     <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```